# Streaming with live captions

Tags: azure-media-services

Is it possible to stream a live event with live captions in AMS v3. I've seen examples like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gN-ZOMJVGEA) doing it with video files. If it is possible, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the following for details on how to accomplish this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/live-transcription

Comment: Thank you! I was seeking with the wrong keywords, ie captioning or subtitles ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

We have an AI based Live transcription feature in Preview right now. It is limited to en-US only currently.

For live captions generated outside of our service, only pass-through channels currently support embedded CEA 608/708 - which requires your upstream encoder to support feeding that into the elementary stream. In addition, the older Smooth streaming ingest protocol supported captions being sent for live channels.  Although overall encoder support for that path in the market is pretty small these days.

Which encoder are you looking at and what is your overall captioning workflow?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try BeMyEars if your OS is macOS.  Google search with keyword: BeMyEars

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).